# Programming Python with an EasyPHP server?

Tags: cgi, easyphp

How would I be able to configure EasyPHP to use the Python CGI? I have been trying to find information on this for the past while to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have **Python 2.7** and **EasyPHP 14.1** installed, you may go to the *EasyPHP* folder `../binaries/apache/cgi-bin/` (where, by the way, you may already have `printenv.pl` file which is the same stuff for Perl programming).

Create a `.py` file, let it be `printenv.py`, with the following content:

```
#!E:/Python27/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"
print
print "Hello World!"
```

(In my case `E:/Python27/` is the folder where Python installed, so it shoud be changed accordingly.)

In a browser enter: `127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/printenv.py`. (The `localhost` reference may differ but `/cgi-bin/printenv.py` part remains.)
Than you should see in your browser:

> Hello World!

For more information, please, visit [Web Python](http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_tutorial) .

It is also recommended to use [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) instead of *CGI* technique.